# how to configure cors in adonis js

Tags: adonis.js

how to configure cors in such a way that it takes different origin when in development and production?

This is how the default cors configuration file looks like

```
module.exports = {
  /*
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Origin
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |
  | Set a list of origins to be allowed. The value can be one of the following
  |
  | Boolean: true - Allow current request origin
  | Boolean: false - Disallow all
  | String - Comma separated list of allowed origins
  | Array - An array of allowed origins
  | String: * - A wildcard to allow current request origin
  | Function - Receives the current origin and should return one of the above values.
  |
  */
  origin: false,

  /*
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply check your `NODE_ENV` [Environment variable](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.0/configuration-and-env#_environment_variables). And then check if this variable is set, for example to production or development.

Based on the [CORS Documentation](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/cors#_config) you can return a function. So i would check the current Environment and then return the CORS property. In your `cors.js` you would have something like this

```
const Env = use('Env')
...
...
origin: function (currentOrigin) {
  if(Env.get('NODE_ENV​') === 'production' {
    return currentOrigin === 'mywebsite.com'
  } else {
    true
  }
}
```

If the `NODE_ENV` is set to *production* only the traffic from "mywebsite.com" will be allowed, otherwise all traffic ( which is for development ).

Answer (score 0):

Just set
`{ origin: true, }`

or

Set
`{ origin: '*', }`